# 0 a esquerda power query

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou com uns problemas, qual o comando para adicionar 0 a esquerda na linguagem M?

Estou usando o `power query` do excel, tenho dados que começam com 0 mas ele não considera esse valor e não me traz nenhum resultado.

segue o cod abaixo.

```
Fonte = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tabela1"]}[Content],
```

Tabela 1 é onde os dados estão salvos

Comment: tentou eliminar a etapa automática, alterar o tipo de dados ´change data type´?